# I want to validate my array json data having value as 'None'

Tags: python, json

i want to validate my json array. also want to validate if array field comes as  'None' then it should be validated also, if array field is not 'None' then it will validate all the fields as required.

```
from jsonschema import validate
data ={"coffee": {"region": [{"id": 1,"name": "John Doe"},{"id": 2,"name": "Don Joeh"}],"country": {"id": 2,"company": "ACME"}},"brewing": {"region": [{"id": 1,"name": "John Doe"},{"id": 2,"name": "Don Joeh"}],"country": {"id": 2,"company": "ACME"}}}
schema = {"type": "object","required": ["coffee", "brewing"],"additionalProperties": False,"properties": {"coffee": {"type": "object","required": ["region", "country"],"properties": {"region": {"type": "array","required":False,"items": {"type": "object","required": ['id', 'name'],"properties": {"id": {"type": "number"},"name": {"type": "string"}}}},"country": {"type": "object","required": ["id", "company"],"properties": {"id": {"type": "number"},"company": {"type": "string"}}}}},"brewing": {"type": "object","required": ['region', 'country'],"properties": {"region": {"type": "array","items": {"type": "object","required": ["id", "name"],"properties": {"id": {"type": "number"},"name": {"type": "string"}}}},"country": {"type": "object","required": ["id", "company"],"properties": {"id": {"type": "number"},"company": {"type": "string"}}}}}}}

data2 = {"coffee": {"region": None,"country": {"id": 2,"company": "ACME"}},"brewing": {"region": [{"id": 1,"name": "John Doe"}, {"id": 2,"name": "Don Joeh"}],"country": {"id": 2,"company": "ACME"}}}
```

data2 output =

```
[<ValidationError: "None is not of type 'array'">]
```

i want to validate data2 also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just rearranged the schema in your code and it validates both sample data. Let me know if it works for you.

```
schema = {"type": "object",
      "required": ["coffee", "brewing"],
      "additionalProperties": False,
      "properties": {
          "coffee": {"type": "object", "required": ["region", "country"],
                     "properties": {
                         "region": {"type": ["array", "null"], "required": [],

                                    "items": {"type": "object", "required": ['id', 'name'],
                                              "properties": {"id": {"type": "number"},
                                                             "name": {"type": "string"}}}

                                    },
                         "country": {"type": "object", "required": ["id", "company"],
                                     "properties": {"id": {"type": "number"}, "company": {"type": "string"}}}}},
          "brewing": {"type": "object", "required": ['region', 'country'],
                      "properties": {"region": {"type": "array",
                                                "items": {
                                                    "type": "object",
                                                    "required": ["id",
                                                                 "name"],
                                                    "properties": {
                                                        "id": {
                                                            "type": "number"},
                                                        "name": {
                                                            "type": "string"}}}},
                                     "country": {"type": "object",
                                                 "required": ["id",
                                                              "company"],
                                                 "properties": {"id": {
                                                     "type": "number"},
                                                     "company": {
                                                         "type": "string"}}}}}}
      }
```

**Note:** If you want to validate the type of key in the JSON data with different types, you have to write those types in an array like:

```
"type": ["string", "null", "array", "number"]
```